# Error In Reducer . initialState . How i can initialize state and use action.type

Tags: reactjs, reducers, use-reducer

i am trying to set logged in user . using reducer.
Errors are :

**Unexpected token && Syntax Error**

Error on line switch(action.type)
or error in brackets not properly closing i do not know
either it will use : or = in reducer initialize and in initialState

**StackOverflow : It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.**

**me: i have enough detail which i shared i do not know more than above**

```
 import React from 'react';
    import {View, StyleSheet, Text} from 'react-native';
    import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
    import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
    import { AuthStackNavigator } from './navigators/AuthStackNavigator';
    import { AuthContext } from './context/AuthContext';
    import  axios  from "axios";
    import { BASE_URL } from './config';
    import { sleep } from './utils/sleep';
    import { createAction } from './utils/createAction';
    const RootStack = createStackNavigator();
    
    export default function ()
    {
      
      const [ state, dispatch ] = React.useReducer(
        reducer : ( state: { user: * }, action ) =>
        {
          switch ( action.type )
          {
            case 'SET_USER':
              return {
                ...state,
                user: { ...action.payload },
              };
            default:
              return state;
          }
        },
        initialState : {
          user: undefined,
        }
      );
    
      const auth = React.useMemo( () => ( {
    
        login: async (email,password) =>
        {
              
    const options = {
      method: 'post',
      url: `${BASE_URL}/auth/local`,
      data: {
        identifier: email,
        email,
        password,
      },
      transformResponse: [
        (data) => {
          // transform the response
          return data;
        },
      ],
    };
    await sleep(2000);
    
    // send the request
    const {data}= axios( options );
    
          const user = {
            email: data.user.email,
            token: data.jwt,
          };
       dispatch(createAction(type:'SET_USER',user))
        },
    
    
        logout: () =>
        {
          console.log( 'logout' );
        },
    
    
        register:async (email,password) =>
        {
    const options = {
      method: 'post',
      url: `${BASE_URL}/auth/local/register`,
      data: {
        user: email,
        email,
        password,
      },
      transformResponse: [
        (data) => {
          // transform the response
    
          return data;
        },
      ],
    };
    await sleep(2000);
    
    // send the request
        
    
    
          // console.log( 'register' );
          // await axios.post(url:`${BASE_URL}/auth/local/register`, data:{
          //   username: email,
          //   email,
          //   password,
          // } );
        },
      } ),
      );
    
    
    console.log(state.user)
    
      return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={auth}>
          <NavigationContainer>
            <RootStack.Navigator screenOptions={ { headerShown: false } }>
              <RootStack.Screen name={ 'AuthStack' } component={ AuthStackNavigator } />
            </RootStack.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
        </AuthContext.Provider>
      );
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      },
    });
```

Comment: Possible typo? Remove the "reducer : " in front of your reducer function in the `useReducer` hook. It's also not clear what `{ user: * }` is about. Are you trying to provide *some* initial state or something? "Initial state" would be the second argument passed to `useReducer`.

Comment: Thanks @DrewReese  i remove reducer now error in below line where  initialState  set  here   initialState : {
      user: undefined,
    },    error is : the type cast expression is expected to be wrapped with parentheses

Comment: Ahhh, probably want to remove also "initialState : " as well, it isn't valid javascript.

Comment: OK . Then How to set initialState ?

Comment: Have you read the official react docs for [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer). Your initial state is simply the second argument passed to the `useReducer` hook. I.E. `const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducerFunction, initialStateObject);`.

Comment: Thanks @DrewReese . I try . can please tell me how i can do with above reducer ? i am beginner . doc looks simple

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226545/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-user10).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your error and issue correctly it appears to be related to how you are trying to define your `useReducer` hook arguments. You appear to be attempting to define object keys, but you are not defining an object. The `useReducer` hook function simply consumes up to 3 arguments.

[useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialArg, init);
```

Generally you only need the first two, i.e. your reducer function and the initial reducer state value. You can read further in the docs about the third argument for lazy initialization.

```
const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(
  (state, action ) => { // <-- reducer function
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'SET_USER':
        return {
          ...state,
          user: { ...action.payload },
        };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  },
  { user: undefined }, // <-- initial state object value
);
```

Comment: Now in  Error in     dispatch( createAction( type: 'SET_USER', user ) );

Comment: Here is my action method : export function createAction(type,payload) {
  
  return {
    type,
    payload,
  };
}